# Getting errors after upgrading magento 2.1.7 to 2.2.5

Tags: magento, magento2

After upgrading files I'm using following command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

but that returns error

> Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.

I have increased memory size but it's using root setup of shared hosting.

Let me know if anybody have solution.

Comment: that means there's a memory leak in some code somewhere - that's a bigger issue and should be addressed as opposed to setting a higher mem limit

Comment: Are there any way to find out this?

Comment: does it give a line number where it errors?

Comment: No, It doesn't give any line number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you can use something like this:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Have you changed the memory for the cli as well? This might fix your issue permanently.